# Assertion error when trying to lemmatise text (python, StanfordNLP)

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I want to lemmatise text in one column of a data frame. My script seems to work with a short test data frame, but every time I try to run it on my actual project file, I get an assertion error. I think it may have to do with the length of the text, but am not sure how to deal with it.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import stanfordnlp
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang = "en", processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma')


def lemmatize(text):
    '''lemmatize'''
    count = 0
    fout = open('text_lemmatized.txt', 'w+')
    doc = nlp(text)
    for sent in doc.sentences:
        for word in sent.words:
            word = word.lemma
            fout.write(str(word))
            fout.write(" ")
            count = count + 1
            fout = open('text_lemmatized.txt', 'r')
            text = fout.read()
            print(text)
            return text

lemmatizing = lambda x: lemmatize(x)

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data_lemma = pd.DataFrame(data.text.apply(lemmatizing))
data_lemma.to_csv("lemma-text-en.csv")
```

The Traceback I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "lemmatize.py", line 28, in 
>       data_lemma = pd.DataFrame(data_clean.corpus.apply(lemmatizing))
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4042, in apply
>       mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
>     File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
>     File "lemmatize.py", line 25, in 
>       lemmatizing = lambda x: lemmatize(x)
>     File "lemmatize.py", line 11, in lemmatize
>       doc = nlp(text)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/pipeline/core.py", line 176, in **call**
>       self.process(doc)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/pipeline/core.py", line 170, in process
>       self.processors[processor_name].process(doc)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/pipeline/pos_processor.py", line 31, in process
>       for i, b in enumerate(batch):
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/models/pos/data.py", line 120, in **iter**
>       yield self.**getitem**(i)
>     File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/models/pos/data.py", line 91, in **getitem**
>       assert len(batch) == 6

What seems to be the problem? If it's the length of the text, what could be an efficient way to deal with it? (I only have two cells in that column, but quite a lot of text in these two cells that needs to be lemmatised).

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening in the Part-Of-Speech Tagger, pre-lemmatization. Try adding `pos_batch_size` as a parameter to `Pipeline`, and give it a number equal to or larger than your longest sentence. According to [this](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp/issues/135) Github issue,

> If you tag sentences longer than `pos_batch_size`, method `chunk_batches`
>   creates empty batches that subsequently trigger an assertion: `assert len(batch) == 6`

Update your code as follows, where `max_sent_len` is longer than your longest sentence:

```
max_sent_len = 4096 
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang="en", processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma', pos_batch_size=max_sent_len)
```

Note: I also use the depparse processor, and had to update `depparse_batch_size` as well.